# How can I show the value of a Vim option in the status line

Tags: vim, statusline

I would like my status line to display `wrap`/`nowrap`.

`set statusline +=%{execute(':set wrap')}`

doesn't work.  How do I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following, which works for me:

```
set statusline+=%{&wrap?'WRAP':'NO\ WRAP'}
```

Here, I used `&wrap` instead of `:set wrap` to get the current wrap status, and escaped the space `\`  (if you need one).

Comment: Wonderful!  Thank you j1-lee.  Is `&wrap` a synonym for `:set wrap`?  Or does it have other uses?

Comment: @JimBollinger As far as I know, `&wrap` is a variable that stores `wrap` option. So you can do things like `:echo &wrap`, `:let &wrap = 0` etc. (`:help :let-option`)